# CanCanCan: How to set permissions on each method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I have a model Report and ReportsController.
There are a couple of dozen actions.

I need to set permissions on **each contoller action** for each role.
How to implement this?

Comment: Check out the defining abilities section in the can can can documentation.  It's quite good!

Answer (score 2):

In `ability.rb` you can have

```
if user.has_role?(:foo)
  can :some_custom_action, Report
end

if user.has_role?(:bar)
  can([:some_other_custom_action, :even_more_action], Report)
end
```

and `authorize_resource` will check for that, or for more control you can call `authorize!(action_name.to_sym, @report || Report)` in a `before_action`

Also pass action to `accessible_by(current_ability, action_name.to_sym)` scope

Comment: Actions can be passed as an array too